# Host to Jail networking with vimage

Tags: networking, freebsd

I've got iocage jails with vnet=on (vimage virtualized networking)

I've got a bridge1 with several jails' interfaces as members (vnet1:1, vnet1:2, etc) these can pass packets between each other.

There's a bhyve instance on the host using tap0 which I've added to bridge1, this tunnel is not able to connect to any of the jails' vnet interfaces.

1. Is this to be expected given the jails' virtualized networking?
2. Is there some other way to get host-to-jail networking whilst keeping VIMAGE enabled?
3. Or alternatively, is there a way to run bhyve inside one of the jails?

Answer (score 1):

Somehow `sysctl net.link.tap.up_on_open=1` wasn't set when I thought it was.

All good now.